# Flutter send json to websocket server as bytes?

Tags: json, request, dart, flutter

I have a JSON like message like this:

```
  static getHiMsg(String token, String sender) {
   var msg = {
        "token": token,
        "user_addr": sender,
        "ua": "dart/fluter-v0.0.1",
        "device": "Phone",
        "location": "Hunan"
    };
    var outMsg = {
        "msg_type": "hi",
        "payload": msg
    };
    return outMsg;
  }
```

and I wanna send this message to websocket server which only deal with json request, if a plain text or wrong format json, it will refuse connection.

Here is what am doing:

```
  void _sayHi() async {
    _token = await _prefs.getToken();
    _userAddr = await _prefs.getUserAddr();
    var hi = getHiMsg(_token, _userAddr);
      print(hi);
      channel.sink.add(hi);
  }
```

channel is just `IOWebSocketChannel.connect(wsUrl)` Here my server just can not get the right JSON format request, actually this is the right logic in Python:

```
def hi_msg(token, addr):
# change this to one account token and user_addr
msg = {
    "token": token,
    "user_addr": addr,
    "ua": "py/macos",
    "device": "mac",
    "location": "Hunan"
}
out_msg = {
    "msg_type": "hi",
    "payload": msg
}
msg_str = json.dumps(out_msg)
b = bytes(msg_str, 'utf-8')
return b
```

How to achieve this in Dart and Flutter? I am not quite familiar with Dart bytes operation.

Comment: What part is the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am just wonder how to encode json to bytes and send to my websocket server, as the same operation in Python codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a JSON string in Dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

...

var jsonString = json.encode(data);
```

and get bytes of the string using

```
var bytes = jsonString.codeUnits;
```